# What is the best way to persist big OneToMany association in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql, nosql

Having big OneToMany association between **A** and **B** in RDB (about 1 <- 1 million).

In details, **A** is a persistence set of **B**, which is supposed to be constantly slightly changed due to some permanent buisness-process. Some of **B** may be added, some other may be deleted. It is important to have possibility to select **B** in a pageable way.

Due to migration data storage to Apache Cassandra, thinking on data model for that relationship.

I guess the good solution for that would be a store **A** as a *row* where columns are identfies of **B**.

Column Family A:

```
A->{
RowID1->{description="...", BId0="123", BId1="456", ..., BId1000000="987"},
RowID2->{description="...", BId0="123", BId1="456", ..., BId500000="888"},
...
}
```

Is it a good way to do? How to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, it is a good way from the simplicity of implementation viewpoint, but it can be not optimal for performance and data distribution within cluster in case millions of big rows inside one partition.

In CQL it can be implemented like this:

```
CREATE TABLE b_by_a ( a text, b text, description text, PRIMARY KEY (a, b) );
```

Where **a** and **b** is primary key compounded from Partition key **a** and Clustering key **b**. To insert, select and delete some **b** you have to know **a**.

```
Insert INTO b_by_a (a, b, description) values ('value a', 'value b 1', '...');
Insert INTO b_by_a (a, b, description) values ('value a', 'value b 2', '...');

SELECT * FROM b_by_a WHERE a='value a';
```

Datastax cassandra driver provides ability to [paging by query results](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/paging/)

And please note some cassandra [limitations](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations):

```
The maximum number of cells (rows x columns) in a single partition is 2 billion.
```